# Python: Best way to convert file with key=value lines into json

Tags: python

I have a data file with lines containing key=value. I want to read this file from python and convert it to a json object such as `{"key"="value"}`.

datafile:

```
a=b
c=d
```

Desired result:

```
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

I have successfully done this with the following code:

```
j = {}
with open('datafile') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        s=line.strip().split('=')
        j[s[0]]=s[1]
```

However, being new with Python and realizing there is usually a super short beautiful solution to most problems like this, I am wondering if there is indeed a much prettier one-line-ish solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open("myfile") as f:
    d = dict(line.rstrip().split("=") for line in f)
```

Unless you actually want a list don't call `readlines`. You can iterate over the file object.

You could also use a generator expression and unpack:

```
{k:v for k, v in (line.rstrip().split("=") for line in f)}
```

Comment: Surely you want to `json.dumps` the result if OP wants JSON

Comment: akxlr: Actually I guess I was mixing up the terms json and dict (started using Python yesterday :)). But as my question actually requests json you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick: `dict(tuple(line.strip().split('=')) for line in open('datafile'))`

However, you should still use the `with` construct to ensure that you do close the file at the end.

```
with open('datafile') as f:
    j = dict(tuple(line.rstrip().split('=')) for line in f)
```

---

A slightly unusual way to do it using [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) (Python 2.7 or 3.0):

```
with open('datafile') as f:
    j = { k:v for line in f 
              for k, v in (line.rstrip().split('='),)
        }
```

I am not sure how *Pythonic* it is to use `(line.rstrip().split('=')],)` to get access to the fields, but it works.

Comment: You can unpack which would probably be more efficient `{k:v for line in f for k, v in (line.rstrip().split("="),)}`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not sure whether it is more efficient, but it is more readable this way. Thanks!